# Meteor: wait for client-side sort of collection

Tags: javascript, sorting, templates, meteor, callback

LAST EDIT: Try `Tracker.afterFlush` in the subscription-ready callback.

EDIT: The sorting was not the problem, it was the new subscription to the same collection with new session variable. Problem occurred because of Meteor not kicking old documents before triggering the subscribe-onReady callback...

I have a Meteor helper that returns a sorted collection (mapped documents).
It looks like this:

```
"currentNames": function () {
       if (Session.get("sortBy") === "rating") {
            return MyCollection.find({'name': {$exists: true}}, {sort: {rating: -1}}).map(function (document, index) {
                document.index = index;
                return document;
            });
       }
       else if (Session.get("sortBy") === "alphabet") {
            return MyCollection.find({'name': {$exists: true}}, {sort: {name: 1}}).map(function (document, index) {
                document.index = index;
                return document;
            });
        }
}
```

The sort works beautiful. I have a Template using this helper in a `{{#each currentNames}}`-loop which also works. But when I change the type of sort by changing the Session field `sortBy` my shown results (the html-dom-elems) are totally whirling around (changing their positions) until they found their final sort. I'm talking about 100 documents in the collection I'm sorting.

Because I don't want my users to see this sorting process live, I want to wait until the sort is finished. But I can not figure out a way to wait until the sort finished. I know when to hide the results (this is when the session variable `sortBy` is changed), but I dont have a callback or something when the sort is finished. But I need this.

Thank you for your time! Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

From meteor guide:

> It’s also worth knowing a little about what happens on the server when the new subscription is started and the old one is stopped.
>
> The server explicitly waits until all the data is sent down (the new subscription is ready) for the new subscription before removing the data from the old subscription. The idea here is to avoid flicker—you can, if desired, continue to show the old subscription’s data until the new data is ready, then instantly switch over to the new subscription’s complete data set.
>
> What this means is in general, when changing subscriptions, there’ll be a period where you are over-subscribed and there is more data on the client than you strictly asked for. This is one very important reason why you should always fetch the same data that you have subscribed to (don’t “over-fetch”).

So in your case, you can hide your view (or show loading text etc.), until your new subscription is ready. You can check it with subscription handlers ready() function (which is reactive).

Comment: I don't think that this really answers my question, because the subscription-ready callback is triggered before the sort.